# Как исправить проблему кэша при редактировании файлов сайта на сервере?

Tags: веб-программирование, ftp, hosting

Каждый раз когда я редактирую файлы сайта на сервере через Filezilla или через встроенный файловый менеджер хостинга, мне приходиться чистить кэш браузера и надеяться, что сайт принял изменения и загрузился в измененном виде. Существуют ли решения этой проблемы ?

Comment: Да, на сайте меняйте ссылку на файл после изменения файла

Comment: Это не проблема, а оптимизация работы, если можно что-то сохранить, зачем загружать миллион раз?

Comment: @NTP если не «загружать миллион раз», то вы бы сейчас не могли прочитать этот комментарий. По вашей логике — зачем загружать, если комментарии к этому вопросу уже есть в кэше браузера? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите, например, адреса на css или js файлы, например, в header`е на этом сайте.

Там есть добавочка после расширения, что-то вроде этого ?v=0dd80f442adc

Например, вы изменили свой css файл и хотите, что бы кэш на всех компах клиентах обновился для этого файла. Измените добавьте к адресу, например, ?v1. Еще раз поменяете его перепишите адрес на ?v2 и т.д.

Название самого файла менять не надо, просто адрес на HTML странице.

Например у вас есть подключенный файл css: `<link href="/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">` вы его отредактировали. Что бы его кэш обновился, то его подключение должно выглядеть так `<link href="/css/main.css?v=1" rel="stylesheet">` когда еще раз обновите файл, сделайте так `<link href="/css/main.css?v=2" rel="stylesheet">` и тд.

То же самое с изображениями на сайте `<img src="image.png?v=123">`
То же с js `<script src="/Js/script.js?v=28caaf93b58a"></script>`

Само по себе добавление строки к адресу файла такого вида `?v=123` ничего не делает. Просто Браузер видит что у файла по такому адесу еще нет в кэше  и выкачивает его

Comment: Можете уточнить куда именно нужно это добавить ? Возможно скрин приложить ? Просто я новичок, не очень разбираюсь в этом)

Comment: Написал в ответе